# Portable class library and .NET ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: .net, concurrency, f#, windows-8, portable-class-library

Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx, it seems that `ConcurrentDictionary` and all of its friends in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace are available for use in a Portable Class Library.

However, when I create either an F# or C# Portable Class Library, even if I explicitly add a reference to `mscorlib.dll`, the compilation fails when using `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Why?

Comment: Code? Compilation error?

Comment: As far as I can see, this class is not available in .NET 4 Portable Class Library, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.100).aspx . Could it be that you are targeting .NET 4 instead of 4.5?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson: when you create a **F# Portable Class Library**, you have no other choice other than targeting **.NET 4.5**.

Comment: Any word on whether these will be available in Windows Phone 9?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The term "Portable" should be loosely applied right now.  When you create the class library project, you get prompted for the targets you want to support.  You'll only get ConcurrentDictionary when you select ".NET Framework" and ".NET for Windows Store apps".

Pick any other and the entire namespace disappears.

This will get better over time, I'd assume, but Windows Phone 7, XBox and Silverlight are lagging behind right now.

Comment: You were right, but I only get the prompt with **C# Projects**. By deactivating all except the two you told me, I could use this namespace :).

The **F# Portable Class Library** project template doesn't prompt me these options though :(.

Comment: I repro that.  F# is further constrained (no XBox or Phone) and has a fixed subset.  Which includes Silverlight so that's a no-go there.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, F# only supports a fixed subset of platforms via portable; Silverlight 5, .NET Framework 4.5 and Windows Store apps.

Comment: Maybe this one can help you : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.ConcurrentDictionary